# Assigning variable to output of callback function is undefined

Tags: javascript

this code will read through a directory and put all the file path strings in an array, however, i want to store them in a variable, but when i do so, and then attempt to log the array - it returns undefined.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function filewalker(dir, done) {
    let results = [];

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        var pending = list.length;

        if (!pending) return done(null, results);

        list.forEach(function(file) {
            file = path.resolve(dir, file);

            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                // If directory, execute a recursive call
                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    // Add directory to array [comment if you need to remove the directories from the array]
                    results.push(file);

                    filewalker(file, function(err, res) {
                        results = results.concat(res);
                        if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                    });
                } else {
                    results.push(file);

                    if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

const allData = filewalker("./data", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    return data;
});



console.log(allData);
```

How can I store the output data from this function in my allData constant?

Cheers!

Comment: Use an arrow function

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer you are looking for, but one way to solve this issue is to implicitly return results at the end of filewalker function.
Next problem is that this function is asynchronous, so you have to wait until its completed to show the results.

```
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        var pending = list.length;

        if (!pending) return done(null, results);

        list.forEach(function(file) {
            file = path.resolve(dir, file);

            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                // If directory, execute a recursive call
                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    // Add directory to array [comment if you need to remove the directories from the array]
                    results.push(file);

                    filewalker(file, function(err, res) {
                        results = results.concat(res);
                        if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                    });
                } else {
                    results.push(file);

                    if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return results;
```

And log allData after some time passes. Here you should handle properly waiting for asynchronous function to finish.

```
setTimeout( function() {
console.log(allData)
},2000);
```